# Radio button uncheck on second click

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, radio-button

I have a LOT of radio buttons that grab a value from my database and if it is set to "1", I make the radio button checked.

If a radio button is checked, and a user clicks on it again, I still want to be able to clear this button. Does anyone have an idea?

`$radio1` grabs data from database and will be either 0, 1, or 2

```
<input value="1" name="radio1" type="radio"<?php if($radio1==1){echo " checked";} ?>>
<input value="2" name="radio2" type="radio"<?php if($radio1==2){echo " checked";} ?>>
```

**Varun Malhotra's Answer slightly modified:**
I changed 2 lines of code that worked a little better for me. But overall, Varun's answer was PERFECT!

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    var $radio = $(this);

    // if this was previously checked
    if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
    {
        $radio.prop('checked', false);
        $radio.data('waschecked', false);
    }
    else
    {
         $radio.prop('checked', true);
         $radio.data('waschecked', true);
    }

    // remove was checked from other radios
    $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
});
```

Comment: That sounds more like you want a checkbox.

Comment: @Amber I want a radio button because I don't want a user picking more than one option.

Comment: Consider adding another radio button for 'none of the above' then.

Comment: @Amber For styling purposes, this is not an option for me. It needs to be on a second click. I can't add anymore radio buttons.

Comment: what do you mean by `clear this button`? remove what ?

Comment: @VarunMalhotra I don't want the radio button to be checked anymore. An empty circle. Cleared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll suggest to add a custom attribute to keep track of each radio's previous state like so:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="rad"]').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
        }
        else
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);

        // remove was checked from other radios
        $radio.siblings('input[name="rad"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});
```

You will also need to add this attribute to the initially checked radio markup

```
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio0" checked="checked" data-waschecked="true" />
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/BtLxY/)**

**UPDATE:**

```
 $(function(){
        $('input[name="rad"]').click(function(){
            var $radio = $(this);

            // if this was previously checked
            if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
            {
                $radio.prop('checked', false);
                $radio.data('waschecked', false);
            }
            else
                $radio.data('waschecked', true);

            // remove was checked from other radios
            $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
        });
    });
```

But do ensure that you don't have other radio-groups to work with, otherwise you have to provide some attributes to specify these buttons like name prop I focused earlier.

Comment: Is there a reason I need to keep track of the previous state? Also this is a real nice example! But what if I have 30 radio groups. There must be an easier way instead of naming all of them

Comment: You can remove the name prop for your convenience but You have to have something for referencing a particular radio button. So naming a radio button is the most common way. You simply have to provide a same name. If you wish you can have different ids for all, that would be the worst case I think.

Comment: Thank you Varun! So do I have to have a separate click function for each radio button I have? At the end of this project I will have about 100. Also, would I transfer this to a database like I normally would?

Comment: I ended up  putting `$('input[type="radio"]').click` instead and it ended up working very nicely. Let me know if this will cause a problem but so far so good.

Comment: I don't think it would cause any problem. You can even access any other attribute too by simply referencing `this` inside your `$('input[type="radio"]').click` function. `this` will give you the particular radio button being clicked so that you can do further transformation. Please leave a note if you aren't satisfied.

Answer (score 4):

This should work more generally than the other solutions as it handles cases where all radios are not in the same parent.

```
var $radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
$radios.click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.data('checked')) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
  var $otherRadios = $radios.not($this).filter('[name="'
                                               + $this.attr('name') + '"]');
  $otherRadios.prop('checked', false).data('checked', false);
  $this.data('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Enlightened me to the fact that the filter function does not have to pass in the index, element function syntax to work, which, in the long run, will make my code shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Change event fires before click when you do first click. You can use them. Working with many radio groups and even if you have prechecked radio buttons.

```
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    var secondClick = true;
    $(this).change(function() {
        secondClick = false;
    });
    $(this).click(function() {
        if (secondClick) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        }
        secondClick = true;
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BtLxY/30/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, which works for touch devices as well as mouse clicks:

```
$('input[type=radio]').bind('touchstart mousedown', function() {
    this.checked = !this.checked
}).bind('click touchend', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

https://codepen.io/robbiebow/pen/bjPvEO

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('input[name="rad"]').click(function(){
                    var $radio = $(this);
                    // if this was previously checked
                    if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
                    {
                        $radio.prop('checked', false);
                        $radio.data('waschecked', false);
                    }
                    else{
                        $radio.data('waschecked', true);
                    }
                    // remove was checked from other radios
                    $('input[name="rad"]').not($(this)).data('waschecked', false);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems like the most reasonable and logical method, but I have a set of radio buttons this does not work on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why but the selected answer by user **softvar** did not work for me, so I came up with the following based on softvar's answer, after about two hours of trying. Putting it here in case it may help someone else. You can specify "data-active" in HTML as 0 or 1 based on the "selected" value you get from the DB.

```
<input type="radio" name="user" value="1" data-active="0"> User 1
<input type="radio" name="user" value="2" data-active="0"> User 2
```

and

```
$('input[name="user"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).data('active') == 0) {
        $('input[name="user"]').data('active', 0);
        $(this).data('active', 1);
    } else {
        $(this).data('active', 0);
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **universal** solution. Works even if you have multiple sets of radio buttons. For example, if you have multiple sets of buttons with the same 'name' attribute. Works like a charm.

```
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')

if (radioButtons) {
    radioButtons.forEach(button => {
        let nameAttribute = button.getAttribute('name')
        
        button.onclick = function () {
            let isChecked = this.getAttribute('is_checked')
            
            if (isChecked === 'false' || !this.hasAttribute('is_checked')) {
                this.setAttribute('is_checked', 'true')

                const radioButtonsArray = Array.from(radioButtons)
                const radioButtonsSameName = radioButtonsArray.filter( radioButton => {
                    
                    if (!radioButton.checked) {
                        return radioButton.getAttribute('name') === nameAttribute
                    }
                })

                radioButtonsSameName.forEach(radioButtonSameName => {
                    if (radioButtonSameName.getAttribute('is_checked')) {
                        radioButtonSameName.setAttribute('is_checked', 'false')
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                this.checked = false
                this.setAttribute('is_checked', 'false')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[softvar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895205) solution in vanilla / plain JavaScript in case anyone needs that.

```js
// For compatibility with IE 11 and older versions of Chrome
if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach) { 
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="rad"]')
    .forEach(function(a) {

    // Initial setup (in the original demo was done in the markup)
    if (a.checked) {
        a.dataset.waschecked = true;
    }

    // Set a click event for each radio button
    a.onclick = function() {

        // if this was previously checked
        if (this.dataset.waschecked == "true") {
            this.checked = false;
            this.dataset.waschecked = false;
        } else
            this.dataset.waschecked = true;

        // remove was checked from other radios
        this.parentNode.childNodes.forEach( function(sibling) { 
            if ((sibling.name == "rad") && (sibling !== this)) { 
                sibling.dataset.waschecked = false;
            }
        },this);

    }
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio0" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio1" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio2" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio3" />
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="Radio4" />
```