# Radio Input Check/Uncheck when clicked on label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a customer preference section where the customer can select if he is interested in a fruit or not by clicking on one of two radio buttons. The problem is, I want to allow customer to leave his preference undefined on a fruit by allowing null radio button/uncheck the radio button when clicked again.

The JS is only adding classes to the radio buttons loaded via php with checked="checked" and adding a class to the parent label for CSS because on front end it appears as a button group as follows:
[image]
I tried looking it up stack overflow but no solutions worked.

```js
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio_checked");
$('input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("checked");
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("radio_checked");
$('input').click(function() {
  $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio_checked");
  $('input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("checked");
  $('input:checked').parent().addClass("radio_checked");
});
```

```css
#customer_preferences_form{
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 6.5%;
}
.container_banana, .container_apple, .container_guava, .container_strawberry, .container_pineapple, .container_mango{
    margin-left: 6.5%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 43.5%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid grey !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.field_title{
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.field_title label{
      text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    font-weight: normal!important;
margin: 0 0 3px;
width: 100% !important;
display:inline-block;
cursor: default !important;
}
#customer_preferences_form label{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#customer_preferences_form label:nth-child(2){
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#customer_preferences_form input[type="radio"]{
  display:none;
}
#customer_preferences_form .radio_checked{
    color: #00d8a9;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_mango">
  <div class="field_title">
    <label>Mango</label>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mango" value="1"> Not Interested
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mango" value="2"> My Fav!
  </label>
</div>
<div class="container_pineapple">
  <div class="field_title">
    <label>Pineapple</label>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="1" checked="checked"> Not Interested
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="2"> My Fav!
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with the missing CSS

Comment: Are you looking for [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895073/radio-button-uncheck-on-second-click)

Comment: What css? @mplungjan

Comment: no @Nimish its already working by clicking on the radio button but you see in the question the preview, the radio buttons are hidden because we have to make it look like a button group, its not working with labels...

Comment: So you want to hide radio button and make labels work like that? Please edit the snippet and include css

Comment: @Nimish okay, updated, check now!

Comment: The classes need css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is all a bit less than optimal.

First off you should give your inputs a class to not get all your inputs in scope, but we will ignore that for now but WILL give it a proper type and anchor it to a NEW div I added with the ID not in the original.

Do NOT remove or try to add the checked attribute, it happens on change automatically and doing it will prevent resetting it.  Use `.prop()` instead if needed.

One issue you need is that you need to find the siblings of the radio that changed and set those - they will "unset/change" - radios are single of a group BUT the change event will not fire in "unset" cases hooked this way.  You COULD give them ALL a class and anchor to that but I present a solution without that extra in the markup.

Don't use the click event, use change, (what if it changes via script?)

```js
$('#customer_preferences_form')
 .on('click','label', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      var myradio = $(this).find('input[type=radio]');
      var isChecked = myradio.is(":checked");
      myradio.prop("checked",!isChecked );
      myradio.trigger('setlabelstate');
  });
 $('#customer_preferences_form')
 .on('change setlabelstate','input[type=radio]',function() {
    // I used the label here to prevent the DIV sibling with title from
    // having that class added - only the label siblings are needed.
    var mySiblings = $(this).parent('label').siblings('label');
    var radios = $(this).parent('label')
        .add(mySiblings );
    radios.each(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).find('input[type=radio]').is(":checked");
        $(this).toggleClass("radio_checked", isChecked );
    });
});
 
// custom event to set that initial state
$('#customer_preferences_form')
.find('input[type=radio]')
.trigger('setlabelstate');
```

```css
#customer_preferences_form{
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 6.5%;
}
.container_banana, .container_apple, .container_guava, .container_strawberry, .container_pineapple, .container_mango{
    margin-left: 6.5%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 43.5%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid grey !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.field_title{
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.field_title label{
      text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px!important;
    font-weight: normal!important;
margin: 0 0 3px;
width: 100% !important;
display:inline-block;
cursor: default !important;
}
#customer_preferences_form label{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#customer_preferences_form label:nth-child(2){
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#customer_preferences_form input[type="radio"]{
  display:none;
}
#customer_preferences_form label.radio_checked{
    color: #00d8a9;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customer_preferences_form">
  <div class="container_mango">
    <div class="field_title">
      <label>Mango</label>
    </div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="mango" value="1"> Not Interested
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="mango" value="2"> My Fav!
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="container_pineapple">
    <div class="field_title">
      <label>Pineapple</label>
    </div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="1" checked="checked"> Not Interested
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="2"> My Fav!
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you missed the point, I want the radios to be unchecked on clicking if they are already checked and via label. Anyways, @nimish's solution worked perfectly!!

Comment: You likely would be better to us checkbox instead of radio as you are somewhat working against the type, but I see your requirement point.

Comment: I added a label click event handler, note that if you use the `'for=` on the label  instead of wrapping you would need to change the selector to get the associated radio by id instead.

Comment: Now you're solution is working perfectly, I noticed another bug in @nimish's code but I guess you're is all the way clean! Thanks a lot for helping me with this!! <3

Comment: any suggestion to limit the number of preferences? Like I want to limit the user to only select 2 options as not interested and only 2 options as my fav? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Add a class for each of those to the appropriate radio buttons and limit the total count for each of those two groups that gets checked.  You could check the count in either function and disable all non-checked ones until the unchecked is below your threshold.  Always allow an un-check but only allow checks IF it is below that point. i.e. `var favCheck = $('.my-favorite:checked').length >= myfavThreshhold;` then use that boolean to disable all non-checked with that class, same for the other group. `$('.my-favorite:not(:checked)').prop("disabled",favCheck);`

Comment: Thanks for the example @mark but can you please add that into the code above? because I tried to do this  but once it reaches the threshold it does not allows to uncheck, it stucks there, please add the example to the code above, thanks in advance!

Comment: As this extends/changes your original question, I would ask that you enter a new question for that.

Comment: I will be devoted for doing that :D because solutions to that already exists but I did not had any luck with that...

Answer (score 1):

Check this out it's working.

```js
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio_checked");
$('input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("checked");
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("radio_checked");
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected");
$('input').click(function() {
  $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio_checked");
  $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("selected");
  $('input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("checked");
  $('input:checked').parent().addClass("radio_checked");
  $('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected");
});
$('input[type=radio]').hide();
```

```css
#customer_preferences_form {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 6.5%;
}

.container_banana,
.container_apple,
.container_guava,
.container_strawberry,
.container_pineapple,
.container_mango {
  margin-left: 6.5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 43.5%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey !important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field_title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.field_title label {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px!important;
  font-weight: normal!important;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default !important;
}

#customer_preferences_form label {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#customer_preferences_form label:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#customer_preferences_form input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#customer_preferences_form .radio_checked {
  color: #00d8a9;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ffb3b3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_mango">
  <div class="field_title">
    <label>Mango</label>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mango" value="1"> Not Interested
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mango" value="2"> My Fav!
  </label>
</div>
<div class="container_pineapple">
  <div class="field_title">
    <label>Pineapple</label>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="1"> Not Interested
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="2"> My Fav!
  </label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** : If you want to uncheck radio button if clicked again. Check below snippet

```js
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio_checked");
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("selected");
$('input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("checked");
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("radio_checked");
$('input:checked').parent().addClass("selected");
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio_checked");
$('input[type=radio]').hide();
if ($('input:checked').is(':checked')) {
  $('input:checked').prop('checked', true);
  $('input:checked').data('waschecked', true);
}


$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  var $radio = $(this);

  // if this was previously checked
  if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true) {
    $radio.prop('checked', false);
    $radio.data('waschecked', false);
    $radio.parent().removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    $radio.prop('checked', true);
    $radio.data('waschecked', true);
    $radio.parent().addClass("selected");
  }

  $radio.parent().siblings('label').children('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
  $radio.parent().siblings('label').removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
#customer_preferences_form {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 6.5%;
}

.container_banana,
.container_apple,
.container_guava,
.container_strawberry,
.container_pineapple,
.container_mango {
  margin-left: 6.5%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 43.5%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey !important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field_title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.field_title label {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px!important;
  font-weight: normal!important;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
  width: 100% !important;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default !important;
}

#customer_preferences_form label {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#customer_preferences_form label:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#customer_preferences_form input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#customer_preferences_form .radio_checked {
  color: #00d8a9;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ffb3b3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_mango">
  <div class="field_title">
    <label>Mango</label>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mango" value="1" > Not Interested
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mango" value="2" checked="checked"> My Fav!
  </label>
</div>
<div class="container_pineapple">
  <div class="field_title">
    <label>Pineapple</label>
  </div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="1"> Not Interested
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="pineapple" value="2"> My Fav!
  </label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2**: Fixed the bug in snippet 2 reported by Junaid Saleem

Comment: There is a small bug in the snippet number 2 :)
Click on not Interested and then click on My Fav, then again click on Not Interested, it won't check

Comment: Walking the DOM 5 times in the click event is not the best option.

Comment: This code is useless - why `$('input:not(:checked)').removeAttr("checked");` remove the checked if it is NOT checked to start with? Does nothing.

Comment: @JunaidSaleem i have updated the snippet. Please check now if you want to confirm that radio can be checked or not . Remove $('input[type=radio]').hide(); and check

Comment: @Nimish Thank you man!! You've made it to work, the code you proposed is clean and easy to understand, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Nimish let me know if in any way I could help you!

Comment: Yeah sure. If I need help in future I will let you know. :)

Comment: @Nimish I found a bug in it, you have to click twice on the already checked radio buttons in order to uncheck them when the page loads, mark's solution below worked fine! Thanks to both of you guys for helping me out, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I learned more from this. By the way I have already fixed this.

Comment: @Nimish yes its fixed now, thanks for helping nimish... Any chance to limit the radio buttons like I can only select two as Not Interested and only two as My Fav? I tried this via .length but once it reaches the threshold it does not allows uncheck, any help on this?