# How to uncheck custom radio button on second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonth to be able to uncheck radio button on second click with custom design radio buttons.

Here is HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" id="sortForm11" name="sortForm11" value="descPrice"/>
<label for="sortForm11">Text<span ></span></label>
```

Here is CSS code:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:  20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../images/checkbox.png) left top no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float:right;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background-color: #4bc2ff;
}
```

Here is js code:

```
$('input[name=sortForm11]').on('click',function () {
   var $radio = $(this);

         // if this was previously checked
         if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
         {
           console.log('cao');
             $radio.prop('checked', false);
             $radio.data('waschecked', false);
         }
         else
             $radio.data('waschecked', true);

         // remove was checked from other radios
         $radio.siblings('input[name=sortForm11]').data('waschecked', false);
 });
```

P.S. : If my input field is visible and if I test this it is working but if I tweak it for custom design it doesn't work.

Comment: Radio buttons are not designed to get unchecked. You might want to use checkboxes

Comment: You can refer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895073/radio-button-uncheck-on-second-click

Cheers!

Comment: @JeremyThille I know they are not but i wonth to let user to be able to uncheck radio button.

Comment: @DivyaMaheswaran i saw that post and code is same, my problem is with uncheking custom designe radio button. Problem with this is because span is clicked and not input itself so because of that i don't know which input field to uncheck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radio button uncheck on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895073/radio-button-uncheck-on-second-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k0sp350f/5/

```
$('input[name=sortForm11] + label span').on('click', function (e) {
     var $radio = $(this).parent().prev();

     // if this was previously checked
     if ($radio.is(':checked')) {
         $radio.removeAttr('checked');
     } else {
         $('input[name=' + $radio.attr('name') + ']').removeAttr('checked');
         $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
     }
});
```

Unchecking it works too!

UPDATED: For multiple radio buttons with the same name

Comment: There is problem that occurs, if i have multiple radio buttons. If i check and then uncheck one radio button and then check and uncheck second I can't check first.

Comment: @FilipPetrovic I updated my answer. All we have to do is remove the conflicting "checked" attribute from radio buttons with the same name before adding it to another radio.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <input type="radio" id="sortForm11" name="sortForm11" value="descPrice"/>
    <label for="sortForm11">Text<span ></span></label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="sortForm11" name="sortForm12" value="descPrice"/>
    <label for="sortForm12">Text2<span ></span></label>
var val = 0;
var val2 = 0;
$('input[name=sortForm11]').on("click", function(){
    console.log(val);
    if($(this).val()==val) 
    {$(this).prop('checked', false);
    val = -1;
    }
    else val = $(this).val();
});
var val2 = 0;
$('input[name=sortForm12]').on("click", function(){
    console.log(val2);
    if($(this).val()==val2) 
    {$(this).prop('checked', false);
    val2 = -1;
    }
    else val2 = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: It is bad practice becuase i need to write function for every custom radio button, imagine if i had 100 or even 1000 radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
var val = 0;
$('input[name=sortForm11]').on("click", function(){
    console.log(val);
    if($(this).val()==val) 
    {$(this).prop('checked', false);
    val = -1;
    }
    else val = $(this).val();
});
```

Here is example : http://jsfiddle.net/wuAWn/534/

Comment: The problem i have is not being unable to uncheck radio button on second click. My code does this. Problem is because span is clicked and i dont know which input field to uncheck.